# What is the length of a Braintree payment method nonce string?

Tags: braintree

I'd like to know the length or range of lengths of the payment method nonce that Braintree gives in order to add a payment method. I've looked at their docs but I haven't been able to find an answer. You can read more about what a nonce is [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#payment-method-nonce).

Just to give some more context...

I have a REST api endpoint for adding payment methods to Braintree that expects the nonce in the request body. As part of that endpoint, I want to validate the nonce before I even try to use it, so if the length of the nonce string is bad then I can return an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support.](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

It is not guaranteed that the character length of the nonce string will not change at some future date, so it is not recommended to use length as a means of validating a nonce.

The server-side methods that consume a nonce have built-in [validation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all) that you can rely on to determine whether a particular nonce value is valid or invalid. Beyond checking whether it is a correctly-formatted value, they will also confirm that the nonce belongs to a particular gateway, among other things.